# parse.form method defined in play framework 2.2.x?

Tags: scala, playframework

Play documentation mentions parse.form method which can be used to bind to an incoming request. I am using play 2.2.x. Is this method defined in this release? I am getting compilation error

```
value form is not a member of object controllers.Application.parse

def regSubmit = Action(parse.form(userForm) { implicit request =>
    val userData= request.body
    Ok(views.html.regconf("Registration Successful")(userForm.fill(userData)))

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [2.2.x source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala), parse.form did not exist then, and was only introduced in 2.4.x.

Any reason not to use the "equivalent" `bindFromRequest` and deal with errors that might be present? Along the lines of:

```
def regSubmit = Action { implicit request =>
  userForm.bindFromRequest.fold (
    errors => //-- 'errors' is a form with FormErrors set
      Ok(views.html.register(errors)) //-- register is the initial form
    userData => //-- 'userData' is the case class that userForm maps to
      Ok(views.html.regconf("Registration Successful")(userForm.fill(userData)))
  )
}
```

I have not checked the source code to see whether it is in 2.2.x. It is not mentioned [on the ScalaForms page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms) of the docs.

Comment: I am learning Play. Want to try the API. I have used bindFromRequest. It works fine.